Closed form $\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^2)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}dx$
While working on my project, I encountered the following sum for $m\in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$I(m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{(m-n)!}{4^nn!(2(m-n)+1)!}$$
I used the integration trick to get rid of the $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ factor
$$I(m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(m-n)!}{4^nn!(2(m-n)+1)!}x^{2n}dx$$
And used WolframAlpha to get that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(m-n)!}{4^n n!(2(m-n)+1)!}x^{2n} = \frac{m!}{(2m+1)!}(1+x^2)^{m+\frac{1}{2}} $$
(Where it looks like the convergence radius $R>1$)
So now I am looking for closed-form for the following integral (So that $I(m)=\frac{m!}{(2m+1)!}J(m)$):
$$J(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x^2\right)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}dx$$
I considered using a reduction formula to express $J(m) = f(J(m-2))$ and by using the variable change $x = \sinh(t)$. However I am a bit woried as to the form of $\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}\sqrt{\cosh(t)}dt$ and $\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}(\cosh(t))^{\frac{3}{2}}dt$ (found this for the first one) .
Has anyone already met such integral ? Do you have any idea ?

The integral is a hypergeometric function and has a closed form of $a\sqrt2+b\sinh^{-1}1$ with various rational $a,b$ at each $m$; see here

$$J(m)=\frac{(2m+1)!!}{(2m+2)!!}\left[\text{arcsinh}(1)+\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}2^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right]$$
Where $n!!$ denotes the double factorial
Take the recurrence relation from @Quanto's answer, multiply both sides by $\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}$ and sum both sides gives the closed form

Edit 6-9-2024
Since OP as asked for more details, I ought to explain.
If we were to take a reduction formula in the form $$a_m=x_m+\frac{(2m+1)}{(2m+2)}a_{m-1}$$
where $a_m$ is a closed form integral we want to find. moving the $m-1$ term to the left hand side gives:
$$\begin{split}a_m-\frac{(2m+1)}{(2m+2)}a_{m-1}&=x_m\\
\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}a_m-\frac{(2m)!!}{(2m-1)!!}a_{m-1}&=\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}x_m\\
\sum_{m=0}^{n}\left\{\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}a_m-\frac{(2m)!!}{(2m-1)!!}a_{m-1}\right\}&=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}x_m\\
\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+1)!!}a_n-a_{-1} &=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}x_m\end{split}$$
$$a_n =\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}\left[a_{-1}+\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{(2m+2)!!}{(2m+1)!!}x_m\right]$$
the key idea on proving a reduction formula is to use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^N(c_n-c_{n-1})=c_N-c_0$. For example if we have the reduction formula $a_n-b_{n}a_{n-1}=x_n$, we multiply both sides by $\alpha_n$ such that $\alpha_{n-1}=\alpha_n b_n$. Giving $\alpha_n a_n-\alpha_{n-1}a_{n-1} =\alpha_n x_n$. The left hand side is in the form $c_n-c_{n-1}$. Which we can sum both sides.
The same idea can be used to prove similar integrals like:
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n-2}}{(1+x^2)^n}\, dx=\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!2^k}\right)$$

How would you sum both sides?

@TymaGaidash Please see edit

Integrate $J(m)$ by parts
\begin{align}
J(m)=&\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x^2\right)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}\ dx\\
\overset{ibp} =& \ 2^{m+\frac{1}{2}} -(2m+1)\int_{0}^{1}\left[\left(1+x^2\right)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}-\left(1+x^2\right)^{m-\frac{1}{2}}\right]{\rm d}x\\
 =& \ 2^{m+\frac{1}{2}} -
\left(2m + 1\right)\left[J(m)-J(m-1)\right]
\end{align}
to obtain the reduction formula
$$J(m) =\frac{2^{m-\frac{1}{2}}}{m+1}+\frac{2m+1}{2m+2}J(m-1)
$$

Since $J(0) = \frac1{\sqrt2} + \frac12 \operatorname{arsinh 1}$, the reduction formula gives that $J(m) = a_m \sqrt 2 + b_m \operatorname{arsinh 1}$ for some rational sequences ${a_m}, {b_m}$, and that $b_m$ is something like a ratio of odd and even double factorials. At a glance the recursion for $a_m$ seems harder but maybe feasible.

Wow, didn't believe you could find it without using the hyperbolic trygonometric function, really nice job !

Substituting $t = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$ transforms the integral to
$$\int_0^{\frac12} t^{-\frac12} (1 - t)^{-2 - m} \,d\theta = \operatorname{B}\left(\frac12; \frac12, -1 - m\right),$$
where $\operatorname{B}$ denotes the incomplete beta function. The incomplete beta function can be re-expressed in terms of the ordinary hypergeometric function (see DLMF $\S$8.17(ii)), giving in accordance with user170231's comment, e.g.,
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^2)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}dx = \frac1{\sqrt2} {{}_2 F_1}\!\left(\frac12, 2 + m; \frac32; \frac12\right) .$$

$$J(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x^2\right)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}\,dx$$
$$x=\sinh(t) \implies J(m)=\int_0^{\sinh ^{-1}(1)}\cosh ^{2 (m+1)}(t)\,dt$$
Use
$$\cosh^{2n}(t)=\frac 1 {2^{2 n} }\Bigg(\binom{2 n}{n}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \binom{2 n}{k} \cosh \Big((2  (n-k)t\Big)   \Bigg)$$ which leads to simple integrals.
Another solution, using the Gaussian hypergeometric function,  is
$$J(m)=\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x^2\right)^{m+\frac{1}{2}}\,dx=\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{2m+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-1\right)$$ which is
$$J(m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\,\frac{\Gamma \left(n-m-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2n+1)\, n! \,\Gamma \left(-m-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

@YvesDaoust. Hi Yves ! I do not agree.
